# How to check whether string enter by user is in mm/dd/yyyy format in android?

Tags: java, android

There is one text edit in my app that the user can enter a date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. I have to check whether entered value is in `mm/dd/yyyy` format or not.  If not I have to show edit text error.

How do I do this?

```
private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        m_Dob.setText((selectedMonth + 1) + "/" + selectedDay + "/" + selectedYear);
    }
};
m_dateBtn = (AppCompatImageButton) findViewById(R.id.date_Btn);
m_dateBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateFormat like this :

```
public void isCorrectDateFormat(String value, String format)
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        date = sdf.parse(value);
        return value.equals(sdf.format(date)));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method:

```
public static boolean isValidFormat(String format, String value) {
    Date date = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        date = sdf.parse(value);
        if (!value.equals(sdf.format(date))) {
            date = null;
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date != null;
}
```

use this method like:

```
isValidFormat("mm/dd/yyyy", "12/29/2016")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex for date validation

```
if(editText.getText().toString().matches("^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$"){
 //correct format
}else{
//invalid format
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    String myFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    m_Dob.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using Date Picker dialog to select the date you can use this code to define your date format.

```
mEDDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){

    class MyDatePickerClass implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            int month = monthOfYear + 1;
            String formattedMonth = "" + month;
            String formattedDayOfMonth = "" + dayOfMonth;
            String formattedYear = String.valueOf(year);

            if (month < 10) {

                formattedMonth = "0" + month;
            }
            if (dayOfMonth < 10) {

                formattedDayOfMonth = "0" + dayOfMonth;
            }

            formattedYear = formattedYear.substring(formattedYear.length() - 2);
            String date = formattedDayOfMonth + "/" + formattedMonth + "/" + formattedYear;
            mEDDate.setText(date);

            String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year % 100;

        }
    }

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(GetMoreDiscountActivity.this, new MyDatePickerClass(), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - 18, 0, 1);
    datePickerDialog.show();

}
});
```

Hope this help.Happy Coding.